# I need help in this code part of my map application and problems with setOnEditorActionListener?

Tags: javascript, android

> **my getAction() method is not working. What should I do?**
>   how can i replace it to get it work
>   i need need way to write it again

```
private void init(){
            Log.d(TAG,"init: initializing");
            mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
                            || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                            || (KeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                            || (KeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                        geoLocate();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Without knowing the API, looks like event.get.... is more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "KeyEvent.getAction()" change to "event.getAction()" you should use the object from `onEditorAction`

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: it worked very well